# Asp.net MVC, calling C# method from client-side by onclick JS event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I got "MultiLanguageProvider" which is ordinary C# class, not Controller or Model. The idea is when user clicks `<a href="">Change language</a>` - it must call back server-side `void ChangedLanguage()` on `MultiLanguageProvider` instance. This doesn't work at all:

```
        <a href="" onclick="@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }">@MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SelectAppropriate("на русском", "in english")</a>
```

- 'cause all the code inside `@{ }` get executed immideately - at the time of page-load. I am not informed about AJAX, so maybe someone of u can show me the right direction to do this simply job?

Comment: It does not get called _at the time of page-load_. `@{ ... }` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its even sent to the view. What is it that you trying to do and what is your `SwapLanguage()` method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, Swap() is extremey simple - one line of code, making CurrentLanguage property changed to english/russian. The idea is - user clicks the link and it fires that method on the server-side without going somewhere like myController\myView.

Comment: So you can only change from English to Russian (and not back again)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Not exactly. When changing to english there still remains an option to switch back. Actually, same link becomes "switch to russian" instead being "switch to english". I am OK with that - the logic is very simple. The only problem is to invoke app. method at the necessary moment of time, not before page-loading.

Comment: `<a href="#" id="swaplanguage">...</a>` and create a method in you controller `public ActionResult SwapLanguage() { .... }` then `$('#swaplanguage).click(function() { $.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage")') )}` but not really sure what your then expecting to happen. It will execute your function, but it wont affect the view in anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `$('#swaplanguage).click(function() { $.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage")') )}` should be inside of `<script>` somewhere across the document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108726/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-52hertz).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand which one you are trying to invoke on anchor tag click. But if I understand the essence of your question, you are trying to call some server side method to change the language, and here I assume you want to save the language selection that was made on user interface (UI). If this is what you are looking, on client side, you do the changes suggested by Stephen Muecke. On server side, you need to add a [HTTPPOST] action method on controller something like:

```
public ActionResult SwapLanguage(LanguageViewModel languageViewModel)
{
     //do the save action => like saving to database 
     return Json(new { data = {urlToRedirt: "/someUrl_GeneratedVia_UrlHelper"}, 
                  status = "success", 
                  message = "Language Changed Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
}
```

On Client side:

```
$('#swaplanguage).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.post( '@Url.Action("SwapLanguage")', function( data ) {
      // Handle the server side response here.
      // Like if you want to redirect, use something like:
      // window.location = data.urlToRedirt;
    });
}
```

Of course, you need to handle error conditions on both client as well as server side.

If you don't want to save anything, and you just want to redirect user to some url based on the language user selects, then your onclick event handler is something like:

```
$('#swaplanguage).on('click', function(event) {
    urlToRedirect = 'url_to_redirect' + '/' + $('#languageDropDownId').val();
    window.location = urlToRedirect;
}
```

Finally, your anchor tag is:

```
<a id="swaplanguage">Change Language</a>
```

Hope that helps.